# How to change font color in Mobaxterm version-22

Tags: terminal, fonts, colors, mobaxterm

Today i have upgraded my `MobaXterm_Portable_v11.1 framework` to `MobaXterm_Portable_v22.0` in my windows-10 system.

In latest version terminal font colors are not as my older version. (The colors are too dull).

**Old version:-**
[image]

**Newer version:-**
[image]

I tried to customize the text colors under Settings > Terminal > Customize > Foreground (Standard Text) section. But couldn't set as like my older version.

Is it possible to customize the font colors?

Comment: So.. I have a friend that will only use the old version for this reason.  Talk to the author (free or not version) and you will find that he switched the rendering somewhere along the way.